# CSS Fixed Footer Width With Padding

Tags: html, css, styles, position, footer

Being an amateur CSS coder, trying to do away with "table" syndrome, I'm having some issues getting a fixed footer to work properly.

I have my footer DIV set to 100% width but because there is a 30 pixel padding inside of the DIV, the footer extends 60 pixels past 100%, if you know what I mean.

How can I solve this issue?

My CSS is this:

```
#footerDiv {
background:url(../images/background/mainBG.gif);
margin:0 auto;
padding:15px 30px;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index:4;
position:fixed
}
```

Comment: Generally ```#footer``` or ```.footer``` are more semantically correct.  There's also the [HTML5 footer element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-footer-element.html), but I won't argue that point for another few years ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a box-model issue.  For more information [look here](http://css-tricks.com/7323-box-sizing/).

The code to make it right looks like this,

```
.footer {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Since it makes more sense to me, I sometimes apply that to all elements on the page (i.e. replace `.footer` with `*`).

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know for future. I haven't used your answer to fix my code but you did give me a thought on an easy fix. I have another DIV inside the footer DIV which holds my contents. I took away the padding for the wrapper and instead, added a margin to the inside DIV. This meant the 100% was true. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Good idea, glad I could inspire you!

Answer (score 3):

When you set width of your element with CSS, it sets only the content area of the DIV. Padding and Border width are calculated outside the content area. You can however put another DIV inside your footer DIV and set padding of it to 30px, to preserve 100% width of the outer DIV.

```
<DIV style="width:100%">
   <DIV style="padding:30px">
       <!-- Actual footer content -->
   </DIV>
</DIV>
```

This shall be CSS2.0 compatible. ;)

Comment: Oh, I just did something very similar before you wrote this. I added an inner DIV like you mentioned but added a 30px margin to left and right. This meant my outer DIV was 100% true. Thanks